# How to fill colour to pixels on the cropped area of an image using the colour of it's neighbour pixel in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing a  project in which i need to crop an area of any image and then fill that area with it's surrounding colour automatically. Each pixel of the cropped area should be filled with the colour of it's neighbouring pixel. I do not have any idea how to do this or is there any library for the same. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!!